# Why am I getting 404s when trying to load Angular2 files with Express

Tags: express, npm, angular

So I am used to using express and so I am trying to port the instructions found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#tsconfig) to the express template.

I am using the newest express generator, then I added the following to my package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
  "systemjs": "0.19.6",
  "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
  "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
  "zone.js": "0.5.10",
  "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
  "debug": "~2.2.0",
  "express": "~4.13.1",
  "jade": "~1.11.0",
  "morgan": "~1.6.1",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
  "stylus": "0.42.3"
}
```

Then in my layout.jade file I add the following

```
....
script(src="/ng2/angular2-polyfills.js")
script(src="/systemjs/system.src.js")
script(src="/rxjs/Rx.js")
script(src="/ng2/angular2.dev.js")
```

And in my `app.js` I add the following....

```
app.use('/rxjs', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles')));
app.use('/systemjs', express.static(__dirname + 'node_modules/systemjs/dist'));
app.use('/ng2', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/angular2/bundles/'));
```

But I still get 404s on the js files can someone see what I am missing?

Another acceptable answer is how do I copy files from the node_modules directory to the public directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a 404 on angular2/testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561926/getting-a-404-on-angular2-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what fixed it, I think it was caching something weird. Here is my final code....

```
app.use('/angular2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/')));
app.use('/rxjs', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/')));
app.use('/systemjs', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/')));
...
script(src="/angular2/angular2-polyfills.js")
script(src="/systemjs/system.src.js")
script(src="/rxjs/Rx.js")
script(src="/angular2/angular2.dev.js")
```