# Getting a 404 on angular2/testing

Tags: jasmine, angular

I am getting a 404 on angular2/testing as soon as i insert this line into my
spec file.

```
import {
    iit,
    it,
    inject,
    injectAsync,
    beforeEachProviders,
    fakeAsync,
    tick
} from 'angular2/testing';
```

This is my code inside body tag in user-tests.html

```
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
  <script>
      System.config({
          packages: {
              'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
          }
      });
      System.import('app/components/user.spec')
              .then(window.onload)
              .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

Is there any other packages to install to enable testing in angular 2 ?
I have installed Jamsine-core per angular2 docs.

```
npm install jasmine-core --save-dev --save-exact
```

Thanks !

Comment: You have to add the `testing.dev.js` bundle.

Comment: Thank you sir ! + 1,  But now getting a different error reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Comment: You have to add `angular2-polyfills.js` as well. That bundle contains both zone.js and reflect-metadata. Make sure to put it above all angular2 bundles.

Comment: Thanks  That fixed the issue !

Comment: @EricMartinez quick question. I am also getting a 404 on RxJs. I have  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script> inside body tag. Do i need to load RxJs to System.Config as well ?

Comment: I recommend you, first to answer this question if you already solved it, and second to open another one with the new issue you have.

Comment: Can you move your comment to answer section ? I can mark as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SystemJS (as per docs), you need to add the bundles seperately. This is necessary for every module : http, router and testing.

In your case you need to add `testing.dev.js` bundle.

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js"></script>
```